# How to add two sparse vectors in python

Tags: python, sum, sparse-matrix

I am trying to add two sparse vectors in python. So far i am able to add and merge the vectors. But I am lost in the end which gives me 'int' object is not iterable error. In addition, as these sparse vectors are converted into python dictionaries, i wonder how the zero values are included in the dictionary.

```
def SparseVec(numbers):
    dic={}
    for key,val in enumerate(numbers):
        if val:
            dic[key]=val
    return dic

numbers=[-1,0,9.2,0]
a=SparseVec(numbers)
print(a)

numbers2=[0,1,0,0,0]
b=SparseVec(numbers2)
print(b)

#Adds and merges values with keys in two dictionaries
def merged_dictionaries(a,b):
    merged_dict={}
    for key in a:
        if key in b:
            new_value=a[key]+b[key]
        else:
            new_value=a[key]
        merged_dict[key]=new_value
    for key in b:
        if key not in merged_dict:
            merged_dict[key]=b[key]
    return merged_dict
c=merged_dictionaries(a,b)
for key, val in c.items (): # SparseVec iterator
    print ('c[%d]=%g ' % (val, key))
print(c)
```

Console Error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/GISN24/Ex_06/E06/SparseVec.py
{0: -1, 2: 9.2}
{1: 1}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kaleab/Desktop/GISN24/Ex_06/E06/SparseVec.py", line 30, in <module>
    for key, val in c: # SparseVec iterator
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Try `for key, val in c.items()`.

Comment: @Kirill Bulygin Thanks. How do we know there are zero elements in the dictionary, this i am not able to understand when converting the dict to list.

Comment: @Kaleab length of dictionary is `len(dict_name.keys())`.

Comment: @krishna So, are we disregarding zeros in the list when making the Sparse Vector in dictionary format or we implicitly know there are keys with values zero?

Comment: @Kaleab `0` is discarded in `if value` statement of your  `SparseVec` function. If value is 0 then it will not be included in dictionary.

Comment: just on the sideline would like to put a reference here, I have implemented two sparse vector addition in C++ using the library NRsparseCol in Numerical Recipes 3rd edition book. It can be accessed at https://github.com/codestamp/largegraphs/blob/master/sparseVectorAddMultiply.cpp